# gallery shortcode exclude not working

Tags: gallery, exclude, shortcode

I'm using this bit of code on single.php:

```
$params='[gallery link="file" size="my_thumbnail_small" exclude="'.$featuredId.'"]';
$gallery = do_shortcode($params);
echo $gallery;
```

But nomatter what I put in the `exclude` param, it has absolutely no effect on the output, the image that I'm trying to exclude gets shown every time regardless of the params I use.

My `$featuredId` var contains the ID of the post thumbnail / featured image, which in this test case is `93`. I've tried just with `exclude="93"` incase it's getting overwritten or something but to no avail.

The theme is an almost completely blank one with nothing but a few `add_image_size()` calls in functions.php and the only plugins I'm currently using is file un-attach 1.01. Wordpress is at version 3.3.2.

Anyone have any idea why this isn't doing what I expect?

EDIT: I've tried the accepted answer from this question on SO, still no dice. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337999/wordpress-exclude-the-post-thumbnail-from-gallery-shortcode

Maybe there is some theme support I need to add for this to work?

Comment: are you sure that the image what you want to exclude has id 93?

Comment: not completely, could be wrong. How I find the id is like this: `$featuredId=get_post_thumbnail_id();`. When I echo that I get 93. But now you've said that, I'm going to see if I can find out if that's right

Comment: yep, just checked the database. the entry in the posts table that is my featured image has ID 93.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "regardless of the params I use"...

You're not using the `include` at [the same time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode), are you?

Troubleshooting ideas:

- use only `[gallery exclude="93"]`
- remove it from the Featured Image
- put the shortcode in the post content

Comment: good suggestions but didn't help. I wasn't using include at all, just what I posted. I think something was not quite right with that particular theme or install of WP, because I tried this on another WP site and it worked as expected. Havent figured out what went wrong though.